# A listener for changing variable in android

Tags: android, variables, events, listener, event-listener

I have a variable in my class , I want when that variable changed , I do an action in another class .
in fact I want a listener for changing variable in android (my variable may change every minute)

```
public class Connect { 
     public static boolean myBoolean;
//some actions do and myBoolean change   
}

public class Selection extends Activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener{

//I want a thing like listener here ,when myboolean changed I do an action (myboolean may change every minute)

}
```

Comment: do you mean activity? and variable mean edittext

Comment: my variable( boolean) is in a class  (no activity class) but I want a listener in  activity that ,when that variable in my class changed ,  I do an action in activity

Comment: please see my post again , i edited it

Comment: if i use Class1.variableName  , I force check Class1.variableName every second  , my variable may change every minute

Comment: ok where are you using that boolean?

Comment: myBoolean change in connect class , and I want to use this in selection activity

Comment: what is that you are doing that is changing the boolean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not possible directly. However, you can make your field private, add getters and setters, and create a method of adding listeners (this is called the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)):

```
interface ConnectionBooleanChangedListener {
    public void OnMyBooleanChanged();
}

public class Connect { 
     private static boolean myBoolean;
     private static List<ConnectionBooleanChangedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ConnectionBooleanChangedListener>();

     public static boolean getMyBoolean() { return myBoolean; }

     public static void setMyBoolean(boolean value) {
         myBoolean = value;

         for (ConnectionBooleanChangedListener l : listeners) {
             l.OnMyBooleanChanged();
         }
     }

     public static void addMyBooleanListener(ConnectionBooleanChangedListener l) {
         listeners.add(l);
     }
}
```

Then, wherever you want to listen to changes of the boolean, you can register a listener:

```
Connect.addMyBooleanListener(new ConnectionBooleanChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void OnMyBooleanChanged() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Adding a method to remove listeners is left as an exercise. Obviously, for this to work, you need to make sure that `myBoolean` is only changed via `setMyBoolean`, even inside of `Connect`.

Comment: This line has error     == >   private static List<ConnectionBooleanChangedListener> listeners = new List<ConnectionBooleanChangedListener>();
This is error  :"Cannot instantiate the type List<ConnectionBooleanChangedListener>"

Comment: @BaharAzartoos: Fixed. In Java, `List` is an interface.

Comment: @Heinzi, very nice answer, you only should define addMyBoolenListener as void.

Comment: @GeraldoFreitas: Thanks, fixed!